# Formatted USB flash drive with Disk Utility on Mac and now it is not recognized on any Mac or Windows machine

Tags: mac, usb, usb-flash-drive, disk-utility, canyon

I have formatted [Canyon CN-MP4A](https://web.archive.org/web/20140405011343/http://www.canyon-tech.com/archive/audio_video/mp3_players/CN-MP4A), an MP3 player with optional FM radio with USB flash drive, with Disk Utility on Mac and now it is not recognized on any Mac or Windows machine.

I have formatted with `Disk Utility > drive > Erase > Format > MS-DOS (FAT)`. Now when I plug it in any Mac or Windows machine, nothing happens. Like nothing is plugged in. It has a screen, and I was able to format it directly from the device before, but now when I turn it on, welcome screen appears, but nothing else. I can not get to the menu.

Is there a way I can format it?

Comment: For all the discussion, its probably dead. Try GParted as last resort. Google it if you don't know what it is.

Comment: Why does the device link connect to some site called, “Best keyloggers 2019?”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I found the archive.org page and updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

With the flash drive inserted, in Windows, click Control Panel >> Administrative tools >> Computer Management >> Disk Management.  Delete any partitions on the flash drive and create a new one.  I suggest using NTFS on it.  You probably will have to format it as well as creating the partition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can not see the flash drive in Disk Management (just HDD and DVD).

Comment: Your drive's hardware is borked. You should return it, if it's under warranty.

Comment: It is old drive, no warranty. :) It could be that something is broken, but I do not think so, because it was working just fine until I formatted it on Mac. Do you think Mac broke something?

Comment: I think it's a coincidence.

Comment: In the last few months my Mac broke at least 2-3 USB drives, so I do not think it is a coincidence.

Comment: I've done tons of formatting to my USB, and nothing has happened to it. It might be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

It may have just failed, as flash drives sometimes do.  But you could try to load it with a linux live disc, which may be able to cope with a few things the Mac and Windows cannot (other filesystem types for sure, corruption, not so sure).  A fried USB stick will not work there either though.  I had a Sony Walkman that ran fine on windows and linux, and OK with mac but the mac would never eject/unmount/safe-remove the filesystem properly.  After 3 months it was killt (killed/dead).

Answer (score 0):

If you tried many devices and still failed to recognize it. Then physical damages may be taken into consideration. It's quite common for USB flash drives as they are quite fragile and unstable power or inappropriate connecting  may cause their malfunction. It also reminds the importance of cloud backup.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work with Big Sur and Windows 7, but this did. It was formatted on the Mac as an EFI/GTP partition.

For a USB drive:

1. Right click Command and Run As Administration.
2. Type "DiskPart" in the command line window
3. Type "list disk" in the window to list all disks
4. Find the disk that is the offending drive, lets say its Disk 1 and type "select Disk 1"
5. In the command window type "clean".  This removes the GPT disk by zeroing sectors
   6.Now go back to Disk Management and right click the Unallocated volume.

Answer (score 0):

It's dead Jim.

As a rule of thumb, if a USB flash drive, memory card, Media player that acts as flash drive, etc. does not appear in Disk Management or it does appear but with a reduced capacity then it can not be salvaged.

[image]

Number one reason for this is NAND degradation: NAND bleeds data, this is a fact of life. For most if not all flash drives it is fact that the firmware is stored on the NAND itself and thus is also subject to this data bleed.

At some point, it's a matter of when not if, the firmware corrupts and the controller will be unable to load it during boot (yes, it boots). Given the fact that the device is close to a decade old it seems to me the most logical explanation.

If you do not find this a satisfactory answer I have a second hypothesis: Flash Drive controllers tend to be fairly limited. Limited in the sense that compared to their big brothers, the SSD, they're less complex and less money is invested in them to be fool-proof.

It's not uncommon that at some 'threshold' the amount of errors becomes to overwhelming and the software (which firmware is) simply crashes and stops responding to host commands like 'ID yourself please!'. Your formatting may have just pushed it into such a state. Some data recovery engineers I know refer to this as 'controller just went stupid'.

If this were a situation where you need to data from this device, the NAND can be 'dumped' without interference from the controller.

Some try reviving flash drives using ChipGenius and so called MPtools that can often be found on Chinese and Russian websites dedicated to this topic. But I'd consider the controller went stupid for a reason, and the most likely reason is shitty NAND. IMO not worth your time.